# I used my AOL login to create this account; can I create a StackExchange account and "migrate" this one into it?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, openid

Either I wasn't thinking, or I didn't realize StackExchange was a thing when I first set up this (these?) account(s), but I used my AOL screen name as my "Open ID" when I first came here. Now, I realize what StackExchange is, and it seems like a pretty beautiful thing, so I want to make one of those accounts now, but I want all my past questions and such to still be a part of it. In other words: I want to be able to sign into Stack Overflow and Superuser with a StackExchange account, but don't want to start all over from scratch.

Anything you might have to offer on "account merging" or something similar would probably help me out. I have not made the StackExchange account yet because I don't want to screw this up.

Comment: "Now, I realize what StackExchange is" -- I'm not sure you do. SO, SU, etc. are part of the Stack Exchange network, which is a collection of question and answer sites. A Stack Exchange OpenID is just a way of logging in (any OpenID would do)

Comment: AOL? Really?...

Answer (score 5):

The process is relatively painless:

1. Sign up for a [Stack Exchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/account/register) directly
2. While logged into any of the sites using your original OpenID provider (AOL in your case), go to your profile.
3. Click the "my logins" link:
   [image: my logins link]
4. Add your new login using the "add more logins..." link:

   [image: add more logins link]
5. Select the Stack Exchange OpenID provider:
   [image: Stack Exchange OpenID provider]
6. Sign in if necessary using the displayed form, and confirm that the site can access your information.
7. You should now be able to log in using your new Stack Exchange OpenID.

   If you want, you can remove your old open ID after confirming that your new one works by going back to "my logins" and clicking the remove button to the right of it:

   [image: remove icon]

Comment: not sure why the link to sign up for a "Stack Exchange OpenID" is not shown when one wants to add a StackExchange account.. having to look for this answer is a waste of time. thanks for this tho :)

Comment: I'm unable to do that: in StackOverflow and SuperUser, the "Stack Exchange" login option shown in step #5 does not show up. Only Facebook, Google, the small icons like Yahoo, AOL, Blogger, etc, and the textbox for OpenID. What can I do?